# CustomerIO Can I specify SMS text in each API request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio, sms

I'm using CustomerIO in a Rails project and need this feature of sending SMS to users with ability to specify text body.

How can I specify SMS text to send over to CustomerIO? In the [docs](https://customer.io/docs/twilio/), I could only find how to set a Campaign with pre-defined text body and some [Liquid sugar](https://customer.io/docs/using-liquid/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right path with the documentation about using the Liquid templating language. Assuming you've configured your Customer.io account with the Twilio integration for sending SMS messages it should just be a matter of creating a campaign with an SMS message action that pulls your custom text from the data you send via the API.

Essentially, if you're using the official [customerio-ruby](https://github.com/customerio/customerio-ruby) gem you'd want to send in an event with the data you'd like to use in the message body. Something like this:

```rb
# Arguments
# customer_id (required) - the id of the customer who you want to associate with the event.
# name (required)        - the name of the event you want to track.
# attributes (optional)  - any related information you'd like to attach to this
#                          event.

$customerio.track(5, "sendsms", :msg => "This is the custom message body")
```

So in Customer.io your event-triggered campaign should trigger everytime an event is received named `sendsms` and you could set this for the SMS action's content:

```
{{ event.msg }}
```

This way every time an event is sent to the API this campaign triggers for the user ID the event was sent for and whatever data was passed in the `msg` property in the API call will be rendered via the `{{ event.msg }}` Liquid tag.

That's just one way to accomplish sending SMS messages with dynamic data from the API and is mainly a one-to-one operation since you need to send one API call for each user ID you want to message. There's other mechanisms as well, for instance if you want to do one-to-many messaging where a single API call triggers many SMS messages to go out to many users you'd want to look at [API Triggered Broadcast campaigns](https://customer.io/docs/types-of-campaigns-and-broadcasts/#api-triggered-broadcasts) instead.